# Pop up para imprimir, mantendo os valores do action

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um formulário que ao apertar submit ele pega o valor selecionado e leva para a pagina destino do action e abre a pagina, porém sobrepõem a pagina atual, preciso levar esses valores do formulário para a pagina pop up sem que o formulário abra a pagina do action.

```
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="folhapgt_imprimir.php">                
     <select name="data_selecionada" id="data">                                             
            <?php $dados = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT periodo FROM folha_func_sal_cc ORDER BY periodo DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
                   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($dados))   
                   {
                        echo "<option value='{$data['periodo']}'";  
                        if($_GET['data_selecionada'] == $data['periodo']) 
                            echo "selected='selected'";     
                            echo ">{$data['periodo']}</option>"; 
                   }
            ?>
     </select>      
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="OK" style="margin-left: 10px;">     
  </form>
</li>
```

tentei com

```
function pop() 
      {
        POP = window.open('folhapgt_imprimir.php', 'thePopup', 'width=350,height=350');
      }
```

mas sem sucesso, abre a pagina que preciso mas não leva o valor.

Comment: Passa via get na URL, tipo "window.open('popup.html?var1=value', ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar como `target` o nome da janela do popup. Desta forma não haverá ação na página atual.

Inclua no botão o evento `onclick="pop()"` que chamará a função:

```
<input onclick="pop()" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="OK" style="margin-left: 10px;">
```

Em seguida inclua o `.target` para o nome da janela da popup na função `pop()`:

```
function pop(){
  var POP = window.open('folhapgt_imprimir.php', 'thePopup', 'width=350,height=350');
  var form = document.body.querySelector("#form1");
  form.target = "thePopup";
}
```

Assim o formulário será enviado via GET (atributo `method` do `form`) para a popup aberta. Se quiser enviar via `post`, deve acrescentar na função mais uma linha:

```
form.method = "post";
```

Comment: Desculpe, ficou mal entendido. Aquele pop up la é que eu uso em outra coisa, o que eu testei foi 

 POP = window.open('folhapgt_imprimir.php', 'thePopup', 'width=350,height=350');

Comment: Dá na mesma, só precisa algumas correções... só um instante

Comment: Fica dentro do while?
<?php
$data_selecionada = $_POST['data_selecionada'];
?>

Comment: No caso você deve pegar com $_GET... se quiser pegar com $_POST, tem que adicionar na função `form.method = "post";`

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.